# Is searching dynamic (webpage) content with Elasticsearch possible?

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I want to implement a website search feature and I'm considering Elasticsearch for it. However, each webpage consists of various blocks of text which may or may not be viewable to the user, depending on their account permissions (like a private wiki). These are currently stored in a MySQL database.

When doing a search, I want to determine which blocks of text are viewable for the user for each webpage and then search/rank on these. Determining which blocks are viewable is a relatively simple but non-trivial function.

I cannot see how to do this efficiently with Elasticsearch. So my question is: Is this possible to do with Elasticsearch, and if so, is it possible to do it efficiently? If not, does it allow anything close to this?

Edit: Each block of text (arbitrarily many) on each webpage has an associated permissions expersion (like a boolean expression where each variable is whether one has the permission), which must be satisfied to include that block of text. This complexity is where the problem likely lies, as there are arbitrarily many possible permissions in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

Well, definitely you can do it, yes. Is it going to be efficient, depending on your strategy, yes. Is it fast, it's super fast.

You could decide to go with one index per role and only index the specific content a user/role is allowed to see. You would then query against this index according to your user's role.

You could decide to go with only one index with multiple fields. You could have a field  for every role and index content accordingly. Don't worry about duplicating the content. As above, you decide which field to query at query time, according to your user role(s)

you could store all your html content in one single field, strip all html tags and configure the field analyzer to leave only some specific tags that you can later on parse as a filter to decide whether or not to display the document in the results.

All in all, you only have to strip the html tag with the [html strip char filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-htmlstrip-charfilter.html) at index time. The field size doesn't matter. You could stick a whole page in there with no difference in terms of performance.

Elasticsearch is very flexible. You can pretty much do whatever you like. It's an awesome technology worth investing time in.

Here is a mapping example for you:

```
{  
   "settings":{  
      "max_ngram_diff":25,
      "number_of_shards":1,
      "number_of_replicas":2,
      "analysis":{  
         "normalizer":{  
            "case_insensitive":{  
               "filter":"lowercase"
            }
         },
         "tokenizer":{  
            "word_char_include_slash":{  
               "type":"simple_pattern",
               "pattern":"[\\w\\/]+"
            }
         },
         "char_filter":{  
            "escaped_tags_h1":{  
               "type":"html_strip",
               "escaped_tags":[  
                  "h1"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter":{  
            "ngram_filter":{  
               "type":"ngram",
               "min_gram":1,
               "max_gram":10
            }
         },
         "analyzer":{  
            "stripped":{  
               "type":"custom",
               "tokenizer":"whitespace",
               "filter":[  
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "ngram_filter"
               ],
               "char_filter":[  
                  "escaped_tags_h1"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{  
      "properties":{  
         "meta-description":{  
            "type":"text"
         },
         "meta-title":{  
            "type":"text"
         },
         "title":{  
            "type":"text"
         },
         "url":{  
            "type":"text"
         },
         "content-visitor":{  
            "type":"text",
            "analyzer":"stripped"
         },
         "content-admin":{  
            "type":"text",
            "analyzer":"stripped"
         },
         "content-editor":{  
            "type":"text",
            "analyzer":"stripped"
         },
         "created_at":{  
            "type":"date",
            "format":"date_time"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

It is very basic but you'll get the idea. First distinguish what part of the page you want to store, some of it that is general, some of it that is specific... Let me know if it helps. It's a bit of a though question to answer whiteout prior knowledge of your crawling strategy/ability.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and welcome to the site!). Determining whether content is viewable is a bit more complicated than in a simple role-based system, problematically. It's more based on permissions, where any boolean combination (without NOTs) of permissions could be required. There will be an unbounded number of permissions, so this ends up being an unbounded and exponential number of possible conditions for each section. Therefore I don't think that your first couple of strategies would work.

Comment: Similarly, part of the webpage may be viewable but not another part, and I'd still want the search on that first part, so I'm unsure of whether the third approach would work. Ideally I'd want it to search on just those viewable parts, to not reveal information via the search (e.g. keywords included) that's otherwise hidden.

I should have made my question more clear in this regard, I'll update it.

Comment: Do you want to display the actual highlights in the search results or a simple title would do? tks for the greetins btw

Comment: I get it. You would have to work out a combination of blocks and fields that would suits your needs. There is no going around it. Section that are always viewable in a separate field, section that needs to be parsed in another (or some others). If you can make that happen, then you could decide to use highlighting if you really want to display the actual match instead of some meta-data. You'd be sure that none of the restricted content would be shown.

Comment: Just the titles would do. Okay, perhaps the question I just asked, linked below, is equivalent to the requirement you're suggesting then?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56614541/associating-each-document-with-a-function-to-be-satisfied-by-search-parameters-i

Comment: Well kind of. But I gave a few more details in there with regards to the usage of custom script query processing. have you though of the fact that you can parse the data and extract insights that you can store at index time to help you determine whether or not to display the page in the results at query time? you could come up with a relevant set of functions that you would switch off according to some rules at index time. Then apply the parameters at query time to get the desired end result.