# Associating each document with a function to be satisfied by search parameters in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch, can I associate each document with a (different) function that must be satisfied by parameters I supply on a search, in order to be returned on that search?

The particular functions I would particularly like to use involve a loop, some kind of simple branching (if-statement of switch-statement), an array-like data structure, strings comparisons, and simple boolean operators.

Answer (score 0):

couple of keynotes here:

At query time:
 - If your looking to shape the relevancy function, meaning the actual relevancy score of each document, you could use a [script score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-script-score-query.html).
 - If you're only looking to filter out unwanted documents, you could use a [script query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/query-dsl-script-query.html) that allows you to do just that.

Both of those solutions enables you to compute a score comparing incoming query parameters against existing previously indexed values.

Take note that usage of scripts at query time can lead to increased memory usage and performance issues.

- Elastic can also handle a second batch of filtering rules that are applied to the actual query result in the form of a [post filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_post_filter.html). Can come in handy sometime if you're not in a position of stream processing the output at API view level.

At index time:

- There is such a thing called [script fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html) that allows you to store a function that computes a result based on other fields value and incoming query parameters. they can be really powerful given the fact that they are assigned at index time. I think they might be what you are looking for.
  I would not be using those if i weren't to have those field values compared against query params. Reason is that I like my index process to be lean and fast so I tend to compute those kinds of values at stream level, in upstream from the actual bulk indexing query.

Although convenient, those custom scripts results are likely to be achievable with a combination of regular queries and filters. In each release, the elasticsearch teams is adding new query and field types that let you do what you use to do via scripted queries whiteout the risk of blowing out you memory. a good example of this is the [rank feature datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/rank-feature.html) recently introduced in the 7.x release.

A piece of advice for you. think of your elasticsearch service as a regular API in your datalayer. As such you can do query processing before the actual call to elastic and you can do data processing from the actual elastic results. If you really can't fit your business rules in there, that would be your last resort.
Fell free to contact me if you still have any questions. All the best.